# How can an event from a process fire some action inside a Node server or websockets loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm investigating websockets (Node ws) and Node mplayer to solve a problem.

I have a simple websocket (ws) loop and a functioning mplayer instance. I can start a track off from my client, but when the track has finished I want to send a message back to my client. However, I don't know how to cause this to happen (properly).

Here's my code

```
    let port = 1337
    const Server = require('ws').Server
    const ws = new Server({port: port})

    const mplayer = require('mplayer')

    //let debug = {debug: true, verbose: true}
    //let player = new mplayer(debug);
    let player = new mplayer()

    let payload
    let received 

    ws.on('connection', (socket) => {

      socket.on('message', (message) => {
        received = JSON.parse(message)
        console.log('Received: ', received['event'], received['data'])

        if (received['event'] === 'play') {  //got a command from my page to play a music track - works fine
          player.openFile(received['data'])  //plays the track
        }

        //send JSON data to socket client
        payload = JSON.stringify({event:'playing', data: 'test1.mp3' })
        socket.send( payload );

        //event handler for stopped events   //***This is the problem area***
        player.on('stop', () => {       
          console.log('Track ended')
          payload = JSON.stringify({ event: 'trackended', data: '' })
          socket.send( payload );
        })

      })

    })
```

Now mplayer allows me to define an event handler to indicate that a track has finished/stopped.

BUT, how can I get this to do some work  inside the websocket loop?

It sort of works, but the handler gets duplicated and then sends 2, then 3 ... responses every time I send a new request from the client.

If I put the code outside the loop and make a function call, well how can it call a function inside the loop? That won't cause it to do anything even if I could. e.g.

```
    ...
    player.on('stop', () => {       
      console.log('Track ended')
      endTrackCall()
    }

    ws.on('connection', (socket) => {

      socket.on('message', (message) => {
        ...
        endTrackCall() {
         //send message back to client
        }
      })
    })
```

The player.on('stop' ... event fires fine, but I just cannot figure out how to pass this information to the server loop.

[For completeness here is the relevant bit of my client code (in an ordinary jquery block)]

```
    let mediaSocket = 'ws://127.0.0.1:1337'
    let response
    let instruction

    let connection = new WebSocket(mediaSocket)

    connection.onopen = () => {
      setInterval( () => { //now request (very short) track every 5 seconds
        instruction = JSON.stringify({ event: 'play', data: 'test1.mp3'})
        connection.send(instruction) 
      }, 5000)
    }

    connection.onerror = (error) => { console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error) }
    connection.onclose = () => { console.log('Closed!'); }

    connection.onmessage = (event) => {
      response = JSON.parse(event.data)
      console.log('Server: ', response['event'] + ': ' + response['data'])
    }
```

I've tried doing research into event emitters, callback, the event loop, but I'm getting a bit lost here, feeling that I'm missing some important conceptual point.

thanks, Gordon

Comment: If I look at the player object I can see that player._events.stop (an array)is having a new element added every time the player.on('stop' event fires.So I am adding a new handler. But how to stop?

Answer (score 0):

I found a clue here : [Node emitter documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_handling_events_only_once)

If I do this inside the loop:

```
player.once('stop', () => {       
  console.log('Track ended')
  payload = JSON.stringify({ event: 'trackended', data: '' })
  socket.send( payload );
})
```

then it does what I want. I'm not sure though if this is the best pattern or a hack?

Comment: I'm still not sure that this is the correct way to do this. Can anyone provide any help please and forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured out what I should do to stop multiple calls:

Server:

```
    const Server = require('ws').Server
    const ws = new Server({port: port})

    const mplayer = require('mplayer')

    let debug = {debug: false, verbose: false}
    let player = new mplayer(debug);

    ws.on('connection', (socket) => {

      callback = () => {
        console.log('Track ended')
        payload = JSON.stringify({ event: 'GMMusicServer: track ended', data: '' })
        socket.send( payload )
      };

      ...//here listen for messages from client

      player.on('stop', callback);  //have to put this after callback declaration, not sure whyI thought stuff got "hoisted"?

    })
```

The key was to create and put a callback function in the ws.on(connection code, but to create the player callback outside this.

Took me ages and ages to figure out, but hopefully someone may find it useful :)